# Fit all child elements inside parent container, Child element should be square always

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have parent `<div>` container with the width 120px and height 120px. Child element should adjust width and height based on elements total count. child element should always square.

Ex:

1. If the child element count is one, it occupies 120 * 120
2. If the child elements count is > 1 and <=4, it occupies 60 * 60
3. If the child elements count is >=5 and <=9, it occupies 33.33 * 33.33

It goes on like this, Is there any CSS solution for doing this dynamically. If not any JS logic is there. I am stuck with this for more than a week. Help me to fix this, Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

Try 1:

```
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

Try 2:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
.child {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

Edit 2:
Sample Image:

[image]

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You probably want to look up FLEX or CSS GRID. Post the code you have tried and we can continue to help.

Comment: @SeanDoherty, I have edited my post, I tried using flexbox.

Comment: @Lowkase I have tried with flexbox but not able to get desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility, where you don't have to set the width and height of the child elements, is to use JS in combination with CSS grid:

```css
/* css */

.parent {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;

  display: grid; /* new */
}

.child {}
```

```js
// js

var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
// count child elements
var childCount = parent.getElementsByClassName("child").length;
// set number of columns (alternativ: use if/else to set column count)
var colCount = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(childCount));
// set grid column and row configuration
parent.style.setProperty('grid-template-columns', 'repeat(' + colCount + ', 1fr)');
parent.style.setProperty('grid-template-rows', 'repeat(' + colCount + ', 1fr)');
```

The settings `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` in combination with `display: grid` will take care of an even distribution of the child elements within the parent container.

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coreuter/6es0frot/latest/) with examples with different child element counts.

Comment: Thanks, It's working as expected, I will try to achieve this with flexbox.

Comment: Glad you got a good anser @Nagaraj, CSS Grid is the way to go in my books.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with JS, but there's definitely a more elegant way to do it, and probably a CSS only:

```
var boxCount = $('.box').length;


if (boxCount == 1) {
  size = 120;
} else if (boxCount > 1 && boxCount <= 4) {
  size = 120/2;
  console.log(size);
} else if (boxCount >= 5 && boxCount <= 9) {
  size = 120/3;
}

$('.box').css({
  'height' : size,
  'width': size
});
```

In the [codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/gOPrYJg) I have set up a loop to output x number of boxes for testing. Change `createBoxes` to desired number.

We count the number of boxes, then divide the root box size accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this will not work out in my case, because child elements count will change, It might be 12 or 20, 25. Based on count we have to reduce size of the child elements dynamically.

Comment: Amended the example to be mathematical. You'll need to add in more `else if` to handle your use case.